# Cordova geolocation watchPosition sensitivity

Tags: cordova, geolocation, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

How often would watchPosition be called if the position is constantly updated? Is this something that can be configured? The docs just say "When the device retrieves a new location, the geolocationSuccess callback executes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The success callback passed into `watchPosition()` is called each time the operating system receives a location update, which is not after a specific interval of time. For instance, if using high accuracy, it will be called each time the GPS hardware passes a position update to the OS. Therefore this isn't an interval that can be configured.

My experience of field testing with Android and iOS devices is the time interval between these updates can be anywhere between milliseconds to several seconds depending on factors such as the current speed at which the device is travelling, the number of current satellite fixes, the environment (e.g. whether under trees, between buildings), etc.

Comment: I guess the OS is optimized for the location service then. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

While the native features also include geolocation `watchPosition()` is actually part of the HTML5 spec.  Here are the
[docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation). The Apache Cordova geolocation documentation covers the same information.